# Filemaker export that maintains table information in the headers

Tags: database, export, filemaker

When we use the export records function in Filemaker we can see header information in the file (i.e., using the merge format) but the table information is missing. Is there a way of keeping the table info in the exported file?

So for example we have a table named 'T3' but when we export fields from this table the resulting .csv file reads:

__Delirium_DRStotal_score

instead of

T3::__Delirium_DRStotal_score

Any help much appreciated,

Many thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker can export related fields too and theese preserve their table name on export. At least this happens when you export into XML. So if you self-join the table to itself by a unique ID and export (identical) data from the *related* copy, it should give you the names you want. (Almost, because you'll have to name that other table differently.)